# Get ssh username machine from what i connect

Tags: linux, ssh

Can u get user name on remote machine from what user ssh connection start?

For example:

I connect to machine 1.1.1.1 with login - 'john', then i login from this server to server 1.1.1.2 like -

```
[john] ~ ssh root@1.1.1.2
```

Can i get user name 'john' on server 1.1.1.2?

If i have both root access to first and second server.
I'm trying find variables what i can send with ssh connection, to send user name, or smtl like this.

Comment: You should create a john user on the second server.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) maybe? *If so*, what is the real goal? (please [edit] the question).

Comment: Why are you logging in as "root@" on the second server rather then "john@"

Comment: "... create a john user ..."
Test, dev, and ops servers may have only one account, plus root.
Also sometimes you log in as a less-privileged user on a test system.
Adding all the (dept) users to all those VMs does not happen at software companies that I have worked for.
I can see value in tracking who did what.
This is a simpler way that dev or ops can implement without triggering a big IT dept SSO project, with controlled authorization that needs to be updated with every new hire/departure.

Answer (score 1):

You can export environment values using the SendEnv option in SSH (command line parameter or SSH config), to specify the name of variables to copy to the other side:

```
 ssh -o SendEnv=SOMEVAR servername
```

but the receiving end (here, your intermediate server) has to allow them (`AcceptEnv` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)(*). Of course, avoid to export directly $USER or $LOGNAME.

(*) for security reasons, the list of variables in `AcceptEnv` is fairly small, but on my Ubuntu Server, it accepts by default `LANG` and `LC_*`, so even if you cannot change it, it is possible to abuse it by defining/passing a LC_REMOTE_USER variable (which is likely to be ignored even by locale-sensitive code).

Comment: Interesting tidbit. (Didnt upvote because Im not sure the question is clear enough for an answer)